# Powershell Progressbar partially hidden

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that is run when a job is done. Unfortunately, the progress bar is partially hidden. This is the code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$SAPIENTypes = @'
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
        namespace SAPIENTypes
        {
    public class ProgressBarOverlay : System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
        {
                public ProgressBarOverlay() : base() { SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true); }
            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            { 
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (m.Msg == 0x000F)// WM_PAINT
                {
                    if (Style != System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
                        {
                            using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
                            {
                                using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap))
                                {
                                    stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                    stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
                                        g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
                                    else
                                    {
                                        int percent = (int)(((double)Value / (double)Maximum) * 100);
                                        g.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
              
                public string TextOverlay
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return base.Text;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        base.Text = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
        }
        }
'@

Add-Type $SAPIENTypes -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Windows.Forms', 'System.Drawing' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$frmFonts = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$chkRecurse = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$btnExit = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$chkMachineWide = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$chkAdmin = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$grpFolder = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox'
$ProgressBar = New-Object 'SAPIENTypes.ProgressBarOverlay'
$chkAllItems = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$btnInstallFonts = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$btnGetFolderContent = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$dgvFontFiles = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
#
# frmFonts
#
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkRecurse)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($btnExit)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkMachineWide)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkAdmin)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($grpFolder)
$frmFonts.AutoScaleDimensions = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$frmFonts.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$frmFonts.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1029, 667)
$frmFonts.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$frmFonts.Name = 'frmFonts'
$frmFonts.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$frmFonts.Text = 'Add or Remove Fonts'
$frmFonts.add_Load($frmFonts_Load)
#
# chkRecurse
#
$chkRecurse.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(680, 73)
$chkRecurse.Name = 'chkRecurse'
$chkRecurse.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(337, 24)
$chkRecurse.TabIndex = 8
$chkRecurse.Text = 'Include sub folders'
$chkRecurse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnExit
#
$btnExit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(870, 621)
$btnExit.Name = 'btnExit'
$btnExit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(147, 40)
$btnExit.TabIndex = 7
$btnExit.Text = 'Exit'
$btnExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnExit.add_Click({[void]$frmFonts.Close()})
#
# chkMachineWide
#
$chkMachineWide.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(680, 43)
$chkMachineWide.Name = 'chkMachineWide'
$chkMachineWide.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(337, 24)
$chkMachineWide.TabIndex = 5
$chkMachineWide.Text = 'Install the fonts for all users.'
$chkMachineWide.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# chkAdmin
#
$chkAdmin.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(680, 13)
$chkAdmin.Name = 'chkAdmin'
$chkAdmin.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(337, 24)
$chkAdmin.TabIndex = 4
$chkAdmin.Text = 'User has local admin rights.'
$chkAdmin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# grpFolder
#
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($chkAllItems)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnUninstallSelectedFonts)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnInstallFonts)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnGetFolderContent)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($dgvFontFiles)
$grpFolder.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
$grpFolder.Name = 'grpFolder'
$grpFolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650, 649)
$grpFolder.TabIndex = 3
$grpFolder.TabStop = $False
$grpFolder.Text = 'Install from folder'
#
# ProgressBar
#
$ProgressBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::ControlLightLight 
$ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 275)
$ProgressBar.Margin = '5, 5, 5, 5'
$ProgressBar.Name = 'ProgressBar'
$ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(970, 75)
$ProgressBar.Style = 'Continuous'
$ProgressBar.TabIndex = 5
$ProgressBar.TextOverlay = 'This is a text'
$ProgressBar.Value = 90
#
# chkAllItems
#
$chkAllItems.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(7, 20)
$chkAllItems.Name = 'chkAllItems'
$chkAllItems.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(432, 24)
$chkAllItems.TabIndex = 4
$chkAllItems.Text = 'Select or unselect all items'
$chkAllItems.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnUninstallSelectedFonts
#
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(432, 599)
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Name = 'btnUninstallSelectedFonts'
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.TabIndex = 3
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Text = 'Uninstall selected fonts'
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnInstallFonts
#
$btnInstallFonts.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(226, 599)
$btnInstallFonts.Name = 'btnInstallFonts'
$btnInstallFonts.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$btnInstallFonts.TabIndex = 2
$btnInstallFonts.Text = 'Install selected fonts'
$btnInstallFonts.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnGetFolderContent
#
$btnGetFolderContent.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 599)
$btnGetFolderContent.Name = 'btnGetFolderContent'
$btnGetFolderContent.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$btnGetFolderContent.TabIndex = 1
$btnGetFolderContent.Text = 'Get folder content'
$btnGetFolderContent.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# dgvFontFiles
#
$dgvFontFiles.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'AllCells'
$dgvFontFiles.AutoSizeRowsMode = 'AllCells'
$dgvFontFiles.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'AutoSize'
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle'
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.Alignment = 'MiddleLeft'
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Window 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', '8.25')
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::ControlText 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.SelectionBackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Highlight 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.SelectionForeColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::HighlightText 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.WrapMode = 'True'
$dgvFontFiles.DefaultCellStyle = $System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1
$dgvFontFiles.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(6, 50)
$dgvFontFiles.Name = 'dgvFontFiles'
$dgvFontFiles.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(626, 543)
$dgvFontFiles.TabIndex = 0

[void]$frmFonts.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

I already created a second form with only the progess bar. But in that case I could not read the datagridview.

What can I do to have the progressbar to front so the whole progress bar is visible? Thanks for your help.

Regards... TheStingPilot

Comment: You've got the progress bar inside the $grpFolder, which looks like it's being truncated at the border of the grouping. Can you extend the box, or place the progress bar outside of the box?

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the item from the $grpFolder and added to $frmFonts. But in that case only the last part of the progress bar is shown.

`#
# frmFonts
#
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkRecurse)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($btnExit)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkMachineWide)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkAdmin)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($grpFolder)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)

#
# grpFolder
#
# $grpFolder.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($chkAllItems)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnUninstallSelectedFonts)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnInstallFonts)
` 

Thanks!

Comment: It works... only this way:
`     $frmFonts.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)
      $frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkRecurse)
      $frmFonts.Controls.Add($btnExit)
      $frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkMachineWide)
      $frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkAdmin)
      $frmFonts.Controls.Add($grpFolder)
`
It is all about the position of the controls.add statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue. The input from **Guy S** put me in the right direction.

The code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$SAPIENTypes = @'
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
        namespace SAPIENTypes
        {
    public class ProgressBarOverlay : System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
        {
                public ProgressBarOverlay() : base() { SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true); }
            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            { 
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (m.Msg == 0x000F)// WM_PAINT
                {
                    if (Style != System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
                        {
                            using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
                            {
                                using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap))
                                {
                                    stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                    stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
                                        g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
                                    else
                                    {
                                        int percent = (int)(((double)Value / (double)Maximum) * 100);
                                        g.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
              
                public string TextOverlay
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return base.Text;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        base.Text = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
        }
        }
'@

Add-Type $SAPIENTypes -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Windows.Forms', 'System.Drawing' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$frmFonts = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$chkRecurse = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$btnExit = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$chkMachineWide = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$chkAdmin = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$grpFolder = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox'
$ProgressBar = New-Object 'SAPIENTypes.ProgressBarOverlay'
$chkAllItems = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$btnInstallFonts = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$btnGetFolderContent = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$dgvFontFiles = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
#
# frmFonts
#
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)     ## NEW ##
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkRecurse)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($btnExit)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkMachineWide)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($chkAdmin)
$frmFonts.Controls.Add($grpFolder)
$frmFonts.AutoScaleDimensions = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$frmFonts.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$frmFonts.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1029, 667)
$frmFonts.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$frmFonts.Name = 'frmFonts'
$frmFonts.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$frmFonts.Text = 'Add or Remove Fonts'
#
# chkRecurse
#
$chkRecurse.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(680, 73)
$chkRecurse.Name = 'chkRecurse'
$chkRecurse.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(337, 24)
$chkRecurse.TabIndex = 8
$chkRecurse.Text = 'Include sub folders'
$chkRecurse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnExit
#
$btnExit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(870, 621)
$btnExit.Name = 'btnExit'
$btnExit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(147, 40)
$btnExit.TabIndex = 7
$btnExit.Text = '&Exit'
$btnExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnExit.add_Click({[void]$frmFonts.Close()})
#
# chkMachineWide
#
$chkMachineWide.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(680, 43)
$chkMachineWide.Name = 'chkMachineWide'
$chkMachineWide.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(337, 24)
$chkMachineWide.TabIndex = 5
$chkMachineWide.Text = 'Install the fonts for all users.'
$chkMachineWide.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# chkAdmin
#
$chkAdmin.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(680, 13)
$chkAdmin.Name = 'chkAdmin'
$chkAdmin.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(337, 24)
$chkAdmin.TabIndex = 4
$chkAdmin.Text = 'User has local admin rights.'
$chkAdmin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# grpFolder
#
# $grpFolder.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)   ## REMOVED ##
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($chkAllItems)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnUninstallSelectedFonts)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnInstallFonts)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($btnGetFolderContent)
$grpFolder.Controls.Add($dgvFontFiles)
$grpFolder.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
$grpFolder.Name = 'grpFolder'
$grpFolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650, 649)
$grpFolder.TabIndex = 3
$grpFolder.TabStop = $False
$grpFolder.Text = 'Install from folder'
#
# ProgressBar
#
$ProgressBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::ControlLightLight 
$ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 275)
$ProgressBar.Margin = '5, 5, 5, 5'
$ProgressBar.Name = 'ProgressBar'
$ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(970, 75)
$ProgressBar.Style = 'Continuous'
$ProgressBar.TabIndex = 5
$ProgressBar.TextOverlay = 'This is a text'
$ProgressBar.Value = 90
#
# chkAllItems
#
$chkAllItems.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(7, 20)
$chkAllItems.Name = 'chkAllItems'
$chkAllItems.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(432, 24)
$chkAllItems.TabIndex = 4
$chkAllItems.Text = 'Select or unselect all items'
$chkAllItems.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnUninstallSelectedFonts
#
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(432, 599)
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Name = 'btnUninstallSelectedFonts'
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.TabIndex = 3
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.Text = '&Uninstall selected fonts'
$btnUninstallSelectedFonts.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnInstallFonts
#
$btnInstallFonts.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(226, 599)
$btnInstallFonts.Name = 'btnInstallFonts'
$btnInstallFonts.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$btnInstallFonts.TabIndex = 2
$btnInstallFonts.Text = '&Install selected fonts'
$btnInstallFonts.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnGetFolderContent
#
$btnGetFolderContent.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 599)
$btnGetFolderContent.Name = 'btnGetFolderContent'
$btnGetFolderContent.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$btnGetFolderContent.TabIndex = 1
$btnGetFolderContent.Text = '&Get folder content'
$btnGetFolderContent.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# dgvFontFiles
#
$dgvFontFiles.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'AllCells'
$dgvFontFiles.AutoSizeRowsMode = 'AllCells'
$dgvFontFiles.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'AutoSize'
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle'
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.Alignment = 'MiddleLeft'
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Window 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', '8.25')
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::ControlText 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.SelectionBackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Highlight 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.SelectionForeColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::HighlightText 
$System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1.WrapMode = 'True'
$dgvFontFiles.DefaultCellStyle = $System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_1
$dgvFontFiles.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(6, 50)
$dgvFontFiles.Name = 'dgvFontFiles'
$dgvFontFiles.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(626, 543)
$dgvFontFiles.TabIndex = 0

[void]$frmFonts.ShowDialog()
```

Maybe this helps others as well. :-)

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot